# How to increase the available space for ylabel?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Good morning!

I'm making some bar plots with Seaborn, but I've difficulties getting a proper ylabel for them.

Here is a reproductible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib
from pdb import set_trace as bp

name = 'test.pdf'
data = pd.DataFrame({'Labels': ['Label', 'Longer label', 'A really really large label'], 'values': [200, 100, 300]})

sns.set_style("dark")
ax = sns.barplot(y = data['Labels'], x = data['values'], data = data)
ax.set(ylabel = 'Labels', xlabel = 'Values')

plt.savefig(name)
plt.close()
```

As you can see, second and third labels ('Longer label' and 'A really really large label') can't be shown completely and I can't solve it.

Furthermore, I would want to know how to delete these short black lines at top and at left of the image.

Thanks you very much!!

Comment: Also, it may make your life a bit easier if you add in some line breaks to your really really large labe, at least for plotting: `'A really really\nlarge label'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `bbox_inches='tight'` while saving the figure as

```
plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches='tight')
```

If you are working with JuPyter notebooks, then `plt.tight_layout()` would work for inline plots as commented above by @ALollZ

[image]

Comment: Thanks you Sheldore. This solves my main problem, the length of ylabel, but still shows the short black lines.

Comment: @Á.Garzón: I can't see any short black lines. Could you please include a figure in your question and then highlight these lines?

Comment: I have just solved it with `plt.tick_params(axis = 'x', top  = False)`, thanks you!